# Does Monero still use chacha for wallet encryption?

Tags: wallet, encryption, random-x

With the advent of RandomX has Monero created an encryption scheme that use it for key derivation? Also how does/did chacha8 work is there a whitepaper one can read?

Answer (score 1):

The wallet cache uses chacha20 for cache encryption. The KDF used is still the original Cryptonight (one round by default, overridable with --kdf-rounds).